# V-Lookup column cannot locate cells which are above them in the lookup range, is this normal functionality in this formula?

Tags: excel, vlookup

So I am running a v-lookup in column B, attempting to ensure that each value in column A is also located in column G. I am noticing that all of the #N/A cells, highlighted in orange in the screenshot, are located above their row in the lookup range. Whereas the cells which meet the v-lookup are located below. Is this normal v-lookup functionality? If so, do you have any recommendations on a more useful formula or how I can expand the search of the v-lookup?

This is the formulas: =VLOOKUP(A1,G1:G438,1,0)

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8uwfg.png)

Comment: You probably want: `=VLOOKUP(A1,G$1:G$438,1,0)`.

Comment: Thank you! That was the issue. Much appreciated